# Db changes not reflected in pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pry

I'm trying to test the thread safety of my code, and I'm getting this weird behavior - changes to the db (made through psql or rails console) are not reflected in pry.

In pry:

```
pry > MyObject.first.name
=> "Name"
```

In console:

```
console > MyObject.first.name
=> "Name" 
console > MyObject.first.update( name: "Console" )
=> true 
console > MyObject.first.name
=> "Console"
```

I verified using psql that the name is "Console".

Now in pry:

```
pry > MyObject.first.name
=> "Name" # the change is NOT reflected!
```

If I do the reverse direction, making the change in pry, the changes ARE reflected!

In pry:

```
pry > MyObject.first.update( name: "Pry" )
=> true
pry > MyObject.first.name
=> "Pry"
```

In console:

```
console > MyObject.first.name
 => "Pry" # the change IS reflected
```

I verified using psql that the name is "Pry".

What could be going on? Shouldn't the model always be loading the latest attributes from the database?

Comment: Don't use `first` and actually load an object using an ID to check that it's actually the same. also check that when you start your console, you don't create another object.

Comment: MyObject.find( id ) gives the same result